# java create file in specific folder

Tags: java

I am trying to create a temp file in a specific folder 
In the image below, you can find the structure tree of my project. I am currently in FileAnalyse.java and trying to create the file in data, under webcontent.
The following tries did not work for me:

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/WebContent/data");
File subjectFile = File.createTempFile("subjects", ".json",dir);
```

or

```
File dir = new File("/WebContent/data");
File subjectFile = File.createTempFile("subjects", ".json",dir);
```

[image: Project layout image]

Comment: `File dir = new File("../WebContent/data");` I'm not sure if this works, but usually with `..` you can get one step back in the folder hierarchy. So because of your packages it could be `File dir = new File("../../../../WebContent/data"); //src/com/packages/rdf need to be gone back`

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: I can't post the entire method, it is too long for comment and rest of the code is irrelevant anyways, normally I can create a temporary file but it doesn't work when I give it a directory parameter.

Comment: trimmed out irrelevant parts of the image

Answer (score 2):

```
File dir = new File("WebContent/data");
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()); //check the path with System.out
File subjectFile = File.createTempFile("subjects", ".json",dir);
```

This worked for me

note:

Your Version:

```
File dir = new File("/WebContent/data"); //has a / before WebContent
```

Correct Version:

```
File dir = new File("WebContent/data"); // no / before WebContent
```

Edit:

You can check if your path is the correct one with your attempts (or if you're on the right track to get the correct) when you print out the Path you're currently working with:

```
File dir = new File("YOUR/ATTEMPT");
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath()); //check the path with System.out
```

that way you can check the absolute path, and you can look if the current attempted Pathstring is nearly correct

Comment: didn't work for me, maybe I should specify that I am using osx

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if there are differences, but I'm using Windows

Comment: Can you add the `System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());` after `File dir...` Line, and give the output for your different attempts?

Comment: sure,
before doing that:
File dir = new File("WebContent/data");
  System.out.println("I am here 1");
  File subjectFile = File.createTempFile("subjects", ".json",dir); 
  System.out.println("I am here 2");

it prints I am here 1 but not 2

Comment: here you go

/Users/emrahozkan/Documents/programs/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/WebContent/data

Comment: Check the same output for your different attempts and try to get the closest one, so you only have to manipulate it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73855/discussion-between-loki-and-emrahozkan).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the working directory of eclipse by going to run configurations->tomcat->change working directory